# Using a scroll bar to control pivot table filters

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table, scrollbar

I have created a bar chart using a pivot table. The table has two filters in it to choose with row I am pulling data from. Currently, I can use a drop down menu to change these filters.

But, I would like to use a scroll bar to make my chart a little more interactive. I have inserted the scroll bars (through developer tab->insert->form controls->scroll bar) but I can't get them to control the filters.

I tried assigning the filter cell to the scroll bar. Then the scroll bar won't move. I have assigned an empty cell and am able to control the value with a scroll bar. I tried to see if I could assign the filter cell to that other cell, but it says, "Cannot enter a formula for an item or field name in a  PivotTable report."

I am not sure of anything else to try, but I think there should be a way to control the filters this way.

I am using Excel 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built-in method for making PivotCharts interactive: use Timelines and Slicers. You can't do it with a scroll bar without using VBA, and even then not without an understanding of the PivotTable object model. There are countless examples on Google on how to use Timelines and Slicers, so I won't go into that here.

Comment: This is basically exactly what I wanted to do. The slicer function acts very similarly to a scroll bar. I just didn't know exactly what to search to find this. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have helped. Less than impressed with the SuperUser mods who deleted my original post and comments, which pretty much say the exact same thing as this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The main motive of using a scrollbar in Excel is to shrink the size of dynamic PivotTable. By adding a Slicer to PivotTable, we cannot achieve the actual objective. Adding a timeline or a slicer is just adding an extra element into a Dashboard. That will never serve the purpose of compiling a Compact Dashboard.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1176714)